# Ajax Error: Console says - POST is not defined

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, undefined, defined

**I have written the following jQuery code:**

```
$('#Submitter').click(function(f) {

    x = $('#link').serialize();
    $('body').append(x);
    $.ajax({
        type:POST,
        url:"engine.php",
        data:x,
        success: function(i){
            console.log(i);
            $('#i').html(i);
        }
    });
});
```

Each time after clicking on the `<input id="Submitter" type="button" value=Submit>` element, Firefox's console displays the error: **ReferenceError: POST is not defined**.

Where is the issue and how to resolve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: That's because the variable `POST` isn't defined. Try the string literal `'POST'` instead.

Comment: **type** accepts a string value. Add some quotes and use `'POST'`. 
More info: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace your code like this :

```
$('#Submitter').click(function(f) {

    x = $('#link').serialize();
    $('body').append(x);
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:"engine.php",
        data:x,
        success: function(i){
            console.log(i);
            $('#i').html(i);
        }
    });
});
```

POST needs to be enclosed with quotes